# Local development of single single-spa child app

Tags: single-spa, single-spa-angular

I managed to create a working single-spa application (with navbar and 3 other apps), copied and modified from https://github.com/joeldenning/coexisting-angular-microfrontends.

Now, I understand that the final output of a single SPA app instance has to be in a format that single-spa accepts. But, I wonder if and how to get a single microfrontend locally running for development purposes.

Say I want to develop the navbar micro ui standalone, with just the navbar in the browser.

When I start `npm run start` (which runs `ng start`), I only get the `main.js` served. And Angular doesn't bootstrap.

What do I need to change?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

From the [Local Development section](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#local-development) of the Recommended Setup docs:

> In contrast to monolithic frontend applications, local development with single-spa encourages only running the one microfrontend you're working on, while using deployed versions of all other microfrontends.

There are potential pitfalls when creating an isolated environment to run an individual microfrontend, such as differences between production and local environments (eg. versions in import maps, globals, fonts, css, etc).

That said, the demand for a standalone environment is there so [standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/single-spa/standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin) was created to cater to this use. This setup attempts to stay as close to the production environment by using import maps as well but may suffer from the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I came across this issue today, and I was able to manage it by making some changes in the `angular.json` file and creating a new file that is originally a copy from `tsconfig.app.json`
the idea here is to add another project configuration inside the `projects` key in the `angular.json` and inside the `package.json` you will need to use `--project` flag when serving the app.
find a complete working solution in this [repo](https://github.com/Abdelrahman-H-Mahmoud/single-spa-demo) in the **angular-app** folder  and this [commit](https://github.com/Abdelrahman-H-Mahmoud/single-spa-demo/commit/e2f0fa7d18c49df54831b4c96264f5b3184c9f35) will show you the changes I made

Comment: This build breaks when there are parcel imports from another micro frontend.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define another standalone mode to run the app separately for live development. (Tested with Angular 17 + Single SPA 5.9.3)
You need to add under "projects" in **angular.json** a config similar to this one:

```
"projects": {
"your-app": {.... // as it is defined for single SPA .... },
"your-app-standalone": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/your-app-standalone",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.standalone.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "deployUrl": "http://localhost:4200/"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "none"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "outputHashing": "none"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-app-standalone:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "your-app-standalone:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "your-app-standalone:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js",
          "zone.js/testing"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

And define an extra ts config file for standalone mode "tsconfig.standalone.app.json" :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Define custom serve scripts in your **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "serve:mfe": "ng serve --project your-app --disable-host-check --port 9001 --live-reload false",
    "serve:dev": "ng serve --project your-app-standalone",
  .....
  },
```

Don't forget to define different entry points to your app if not already defined:
**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**main.single-spa.ts**

```
....
const lifecycles = singleSpaAngular({
  bootstrapFunction: (singleSpaProps) => {
    singleSpaPropsSubject.next(singleSpaProps);
    return bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
        getSingleSpaExtraProviders(),
        provideRouter(routes),
      ],
    });
  },
  template: '<app-root />',
  Router,
  NavigationStart,
  NgZone,
});

export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;
```